# ngIf once with angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm using tabs on a Angular app, using ngIf to lazy load the directives and controls inside them when the users needs to. The problem is that I don't want to recreate the tab if the users navigate through them, and with that in mind I'm using this *trick* to initialize the tab just once and show it when then users needed:

```
<button ng-click="tab.show=!tab.show">Toggle tab</div>

<div ng-if="tab.show || tab.initialized" ng-show="tab.show" ng-init="tab.initialized=true">
tab content
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is implement this behaviour with a custom directive, something like `ng-if-once="tab.show"`, reusing the core ngIf and ngShow directives if possible. Any ideas?

*EDIT*

This is my temporal solution, but ngIf keeps working after a truthy value is set:

```
app.directive('ngIfOnce', ['ngIfDirective', 'ngShowDirective', function (ngIfDirective, ngShowDirective) {
var ngIf = ngIfDirective[0];
var ngShow = ngShowDirective[0];

return {
    transclude: ngIf.transclude,
    priority: ngIf.priority,
    terminal: ngIf.terminal,
    restrict: ngIf.restrict,
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attr) {
        $attr.ngIf = $attr.ngShow = $attr['ngIfOnce'];

        var unregisterWatcher = $scope.$watch($attr.ngIf, function (newVal) {
            if (newVal) {
                $attr.ngIf = true;
                unregisterWatcher();
            }
        });

        ngIf.link.apply(ngIf, arguments);
        ngShow.link.apply(ngShow, arguments);
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: definitely possible, can you please share what have you tried??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a possible solution:

```
myApp.directive("ngIfOnce", function () {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    template: "<span ng-show='originalNgIf' ng-if='initialized' ng-transclude></span>",
    scope:{
        ngIfOnce: '='
    },
    link: function (scope, attr) {
        console.log( scope.ngIfOnce );            
        scope.$watch('ngIfOnce', function (newVal, oldVal) {
            console.log("changed" + newVal);
            scope.originalNgIf = newVal;
            if (scope.initialized === undefined && scope.originalNgIf === true) scope.initialized = true;

        });

     }
    }
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/wvg9g50b/

It transcludes the ngIfOnce content and executes the ngIf only once, while the ngShow is executed every time the variable passed as an attribute changes